# How do I construct a cross database query in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

In our last episode ([How I constructed a cross database query in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972943/how-do-i-construct-a-cross-database-query-in-mysql)) I learned how to construct a cross database query in MySQL. This worked great but when our hero tried to use this newfound knowledge in PHP he found his best friend FAIL waiting for him.

I took a look at `mysql_select_db` for PHP. This seems to imply that if I want to use MySQL with PHP, I have a couple of choices:

1. Use `mysql_select_db` but be stuck with only using one db at a time. This is our current setup and putting a database as a namespace identifier doesn't seem to work (it works fine in the MySQL shell so I know it's not a problem with our MySQL server setup).
2. Don't use `mysql_select_db`. From some of the examples I've seen, this seems to mean that I have to specify the db for every query that I make. This makes sense since I haven't used `mysql_select_db` to tell PHP what db I want to access. This also makes sad since I don't want to go through all my code and prepend a db name to every query.

Is there something better than this? Is there a way for me to do a cross db MySQL query in PHP without having to something crazy like (2)?

**CLARIFICATION**: None of the proposed answers actually let me do a cross db query. Instead, they allow me to access two different DBs separately. I want a solution that allows me to do something like `SELECT foreign_db.login.username, firstname, lastname from foreign_db.login, user where ...` NOT just make different queries to different DBs. For what it's worth, (2) doesn't work for me.

Comment: After some testing, for whatever reason, my setup doesn't allow me to do number (2). I always need to use mysql_select_db. Something that does work is to use mysql_select_db to switch between dbs, but this doesn't allow me to do cross db queries. I'm thinking of something like select * from main_db.login, customerInfo where... etc.

Comment: (2) is the correct answer. My PHP server does hundreds of such queries a minute with part of the data from a second database specified by name. So the question is less "How do I do this?" and more "Why isn't this working?"

Comment: After some intense digging around, I got it to work like you would think it should: SELECT FROM * foreigndb.login WHERE... Not sure who gets the bounty... Maybe I can just demote this question... and then cast some reputation points in the charity bin.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You will need your databases to run on the same host.

If so, you should be able to use mysql_select_db on your favourite/default db and manually specify a foreign database.

```
$db = mysql_connect($hots, $user, $password);
mysql_select_db('my_most_used_db', $db);

$q = mysql_query("
    SELECT *
    FROM   table_on_default_db a, `another_db`.`table_on_another_db` b
    WHERE  a.id = b.fk_id
");
```

If your databases run on a different host, you won't be able to join directly. But you can then make 2 queries.

```
$db1 = mysql_connect($host1, $user1, $password1);
$db2 = mysql_connect($host2, $user2, $password2);

$q1 = mysql_query("
    SELECT id
    FROM   table
    WHERE  [..your criteria for db1 here..]
", $db1);
$tmp = array();
while($val = mysql_fetch_array($q1))
    $tmp[] = $val['id'];

$q2 = mysql_query("
    SELECT *
    FROM   table2
    WHERE  fk_id in (".implode(', ', $tmp).")
", $db2);
```

Comment: How to print output for above code "databases run on a different host"?

Answer (score 6):

After reading your clarification, I am under the impression that you actually want to query tables residing in two separate MySQL server instances. At least, your clarification text:

> SELECT foreign_db.login.username, firstname, lastname from foreign_db.login, user where

suggests that you want to run one query while being logged in as two users (which may or may not reside on the same mysql server instance).

In your question, you said you wanted to query data from two different databases, but it is important to realize that one MySQL instance can have many, many databases. For multiple databases managed by the same mysql instance, the solution proposed in the question you linked to simply works: just prefix the table name with the name of the databases, separating database and table names with a dot: `<db-name>.<table-name>`.

But, like i pointed out, this only works if:

1. all databases you access in one query reside on the same server - that is, are managed by the same MySQL instance
2. the user that is connected to the database has the right privileges to access both tables.

**Scenario1: databases on same host: grant appopriate privileges and qualify table names**

So if the tables actually reside on the same mysql instance, there is no need for a second login or connection - simply grant the database user you use to connect to the datbase the appropriate privileges to select from all tables you need. You can do that with the `GRANT` syntax, documented here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

For example, `GRANT SELECT ON sakila.film TO 'test'@'%'` will allow the user `test@%` to select data from the `film` table in the `sakila` database. After doing that, said user can refer to this table using `sakila.film` (so-called qualified table name), or if the current database is set to `sakila`, simply as `film`

**Scenario2: databases managed by different MySQL instances: FEDERATED engine**

If the tables you want to access are actually managed by two different MySQL instances, there is one trick that may or may not work, depending on your configuration. Since MySQL 5.0 mysql supports the `FEDERATED` storage engine. This lets you create a table that is not actually a table, but a peephole to a table on a remote server. This engine is documented here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/federated-storage-engine.html

For example, if you know there is this table in the `misc` database on the remote host:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
    id int not null primary key
,   name varchar(10) not null unique
)
```

you can make a local 'pointer' to that remote table using this:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
    id int not null primary key
,   name varchar(10) not null unique
)
ENGINE = FEDERATED
CONNECTION='mysql://<user>@<remote-server>:<remote-port>/misc/t';
```

Unfortunately, the `FEDERATED` engine is not always available, so you have to check first if you can even use that. But suppose it is, then you can simply use the local table t in your queries, just like any other table, and MySQL will communicate with the remote server and perform the appropriate operations on the physical table on the other side.

Caveat: there are several optimization issues with FEDERATED tables. You should find out if and to what extent these apply to you. For instance, applying a `WHERE` to a federated table can in many cases result in the entire table contents being pullled over the wire to your local server, where the actual filtering will be appplied. Another issue is with table creation: you have to be very sure that the definitions of the federated table and the table it is pointing to match exacty, except for the ENGINE clause (and CONNECTION). If you have for example a different character set, the data may arrive completely garbled after travelling over the wire.

If you want to use `FEDERATED` tables, do read this article http://oreilly.com/pub/a/databases/2006/08/10/mysql-federated-tables.html to decide if its right for your particular use case.

If you think you do need it, I have a utility to create federated tables here: http://forge.mysql.com/tools/tool.php?id=54

**Scenario3: can't use FEDERATED, but tables on different MySQL instances**

Finally, if you have tables on different MySQL instances, but cannot for some reason use the federated table engine, your a out of luck I'm afraid. You are simply going to have to execute queries to both MySQL instances, receive the results and do something intelligent with it in PHP. depending on your exact requirements, this may be a perfectly viable solution

I guess you need to decide for yourself which part of my answer best appeals to your problem, and add a comment in case you need more help. TIA Roland.

Answer (score 3):

A solution might be to :

- use `mysql_select_db` to select the "default" *(i.e. most used)* database
- and specify the DB name only in queries that have to work with the "second" (i.e. least used) database.

But this is only a viable solution if you have one DB that's more used than the other...

Out of curiosity : did you try establishing several connections to your DB server -- i.e. one for each database ?

You might be able to :

- connect to the first DB with [`mysql_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php), and, then, select the first DB with [`mysql_select_db`](http://php.net/mysql_select_db)
- and, then, connect to the second DB, passing `true` for the `new_link` parameter of `mysql_connect` if necessary, and, then, selecting the second DB with `mysql_select_db`

Then, work with the connection identifier returned by the first, or second, call to `mysql_connect`, depending on which DB you want to issue queries.

As a sidenote : the "best" / "cleanest" solution would be not using `mysql_*` functions directly, but working with some kind of ORM framework, that would have the ability to work with several DB connections at the same time *(not sure, but maybe [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) can do that -- it's a real good ORM)*

Answer (score 1):

I set up tables in separate test databases as follows:

```
mysql> use test;
mysql> create table foo as select 42 as id from dual;
mysql> create database test2;
mysql> use test2;
mysql> create table bar as select 42 as id from dual;
```

I ran the following PHP script with MySQL 5.1.41 and PHP 5.3.1 on Mac OS X:

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'XXXX')
 or die('There was a problem connecting to the database.');
mysql_select_db('test');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM foo JOIN test2.bar USING (id)";
if (($result = mysql_query($sql)) === FALSE) {
  die(mysql_error());
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  print_r($row);
}
```

This test succeeds.  The result is the join between the two tables in separate databases.

You should always be able to select from table(s) qualified by their respective database names in SQL.  The mysql API in PHP does not restrict you to querying one database.

You should always be able to omit the database qualifier for the "current" database, which you declare with `mysql_select_db()`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the code that you want

---

```
//create links
$link1 = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
$link2 = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');

//set db on every link
mysql_select_db('foo', $link1);
mysql_select_db('bar', $link2);

//do query with specified link
$result1 = mysql_query($query1,$link1);
$result2 = mysql_query($query2,$link2);
```

Note that we didn't do a mysql_select_db between queries , and we didn't use the database name in the query either.

Comment: The two mysql_connects that you call won't do anything significant. From the documentation (http://cn.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php):

"If a second call is made to mysql_connect() with the same arguments, no new link will be established, but instead, the link identifier of the already opened link will be returned. "

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are `SELECT`ing from multiple tables you have to sepcify an alias. So it's pretty simple from there:

```
SELECT
    a.id, a.name, a.phone,
    b.service, b.provider

FROM
    `people` AS a,

LEFT JOIN
    `other_database`.`providers` AS b ON a.id = b.userid

WHERE
    a.username = 'sirlancelot'
```

As others on this page have mentioned, the database must be on the same host and instance. You cannot query a database from another server with this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

**The less verbose option you have is provided by the [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/use.html) itself:**

> The following example accesses the
>   author table from the db1 database and
>   the editor  table from the db2
>   database:

```
USE db1;
SELECT author_name, editor_name FROM author, db2.editor
WHERE author.editor_id = db2.editor.editor_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use option two: "Don't use `mysql_select_db`" and then use [`mysql_db_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-db-query.php) instead of mysql_query ... which is a simple find and replace.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried this simple code in my computer and it works perfectly:

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '....');
mysql_select_db('aliro');

$sql = 'select * ' .
    'from aliro_permissions a ' .
    'left join cmsmadesimple.cms_permissions b on a.id=b.permission_id ';

$res = mysql_query($sql)
    or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    print_r($row);
}

?>
```

(Of course, the query itself is meaningless, it's just an example.)

So I can't really see what your exact problem is. If you want a syntax that's simpler that this, you'll have to provide an example of what kind of SQL you want to write.