# Can you do queries against two databases if mysql_select_db was already used?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database, database-connection

I have code that in the connection setup selects the database using mysql_select_db().

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
mysql_select_db("database1");
```

Can I later run a query against two databases such as:

```
SELECT database1.row, database2.row 
FROM database1.table, database2.table 
WHERE database1.row = database2.otherrow
```

even though "database1" was already selected at first?  Or is there a method for *unselecting* the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can.** Also check this out: **[How do I construct a cross database query in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999235/how-do-i-construct-a-cross-database-query-in-php)**