# Updating table A.type = B.type WHERE A.id = B.id

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in different databases:

In the database named CRMALPHA:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contacts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `accountId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `lName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `workPhone` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `workPhoneExt` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cellPhone` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `altPhone` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `altPhoneDescription` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `dob` date NOT NULL,
  `createdDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `createdById` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `notes` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `isDeleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `accountId` (`accountId`,`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=12006 ;
```

In the DB named scottse1_lifestyle_test

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_customers_contact_types` (
  `ContactId` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `TypeId` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ContactId`,`TypeId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I need to:

```
UPDATE crmalpha.contacts 
SET type = scottse1_lifestyle_test.tbl_customers_contact_types.TypeID 
WHERE scottse1_lifestyle_test.tbl_customers_contact_types.ContactId = crmalpha.contacts.id
```

This causes the following error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'scottse1_lifestyle_test.tbl_customers_contact_types.ContactId' in 'where clause'
```

What am I doing wrong?

### EDIT

Solution was:

```
UPDATE crmalpha.contacts c
JOIN scottse1_lifestyle_test.tbl_customers_contact_types t
ON t.ContactId = c.id
SET c.type = t.TypeId
```

Comment: Does MSQL support cross DB SQL? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999235/how-do-i-construct-a-cross-database-query-in-php

Comment: Yes, I have done several other loads cross-db

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the table in commaseperated way:

```
UPDATE CRMALPHA.contacts, scottse1_lifestyle_test.tbl_customers_contact_types
SET Type = scottse1_lifestyle_test.tbl_customers_contact_types.TypeID 
WHERE scottse1_lifestyle_test.tbl_customers_contact_types.ContactId = CRMALPHA.contacts.id
```

Comment: Can you do a SELECT with same result, like..
`SELECT * FROM crmalpha.contacts, scottse1_lifestyle_test.tbl_customers_contact_types
WHERE scottse1_lifestyle_test.tbl_customers_contact_types.ContactId = crmalpha.contacts.id`

Comment: Yes that works.  222 rows returned.  Seems low.  I have 10k contacts 700 contact_types

Comment: then should the update statement working too. You have to check the rights of the sql-user for updating in these databases.

Comment: what mysql-version you have?

Comment: Please verify your problem with this article:
[MySQLDev](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html)

Comment: Maybe "myisam joining to innodb", is your problem.

Comment: I have no idea the implications of that

Comment: On my local machine with mysql 5.1 and root user the sql-statement in my answer works. Verify MySQL-Rights, be sure that tables are not empty, try to use only innoDB-Engines for your Tables or manage it with PHP-Code (bad idea)