# Cross server join in PHP sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sqlite

I have two sql hosts on which I want to run my sql query.
It should look something like this:
Assuming two hosts -> host1.DB1 & host2.DB2

```
select a.*, b.* from host1.DB1.table as a join host2.DB2.table on a.key=b.key
```

So far, I have read many answers on this forum as well as on google but no luck any where..!!

Comment: this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this isn't possible as you can only run the query through one connector, which can only connect to one database server at a time. You'll need to run one query then run a second query and merge the results in PHP.

The only thing that comes remotely close is if you're connecting to two databases on the same host. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999235/how-do-i-construct-a-cross-database-query-in-php) covers that.

An example of this would be:

```
$rowsA = $rowsB = [];
$mysqliA = new mysqli($hostA, $usernameA, $passwordA, $databaseA);
$mysqliB = new mysqli($hostB, $usernameB, $passwordB, $databaseB);

$query = "SELECT id, A1, A2, A3 FROM tableA";
$resultA = $mysqliA->query($query);
while($row = $resultA->fetch_assoc())
{
    $rowsA[$row['id']] = $row;
}

$query = "SELECT id, B1, B2, B3 FROM tableB";
$resultB = $mysqliB->query($query);
while($row = $resultB->fetch_assoc())
{
    $rowsB[$row['id']] = $row;
}

$all_rows = array_merge_recursive($rowsA, $rowsB);
```

Check out this [eval.in](https://eval.in/361521) example of the [`array_merge_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) working.

Comment: Thanks..!! Any suggestion on how to do it? I am new to this. As far as I know, array_merge won't help because it appends the datasets. TIA..

Comment: `array_merge` should work fine with the two results.

Comment: Sorry, it's `array_merge_recursive` you want, [see this eval.in](https://eval.in/361521) as an example.

Comment: Will try it and get back with results..!!

Comment: @PrateekSaxena I've added an example in my answer for you.

Comment: In the code you have shared, you are adding 'id' column to an array, will $all_rows give me id, A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3?

Comment: Yes, if the same array key is present then it keeps only one of them.

Comment: Hey, one last thing. How do I print the result of this in tabular form? I have tried foreach. I have checked that $all_rows have values using print_r.

Comment: Styphon, Any suggestion on my precious comment?

Comment: I suggest you try `foreach` again. It's what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how many records you want to join, it make take a lot of time to do that via code.

If yor're the DBA or the DBA is willing to help you, why don't you try with a linked server??

With a linked server, you can run the query in either of the servers with PHP, so you code will look something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT a.id_col, b.col, a.other_col 
FROM [SERVER1].[your_db].[dbo].your_table
INNER JOIN your_other_table b
ON a.id_col = b.id_col";
```

That way, you can run your query from either server.

If you're using SQL Server, you can do it like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx) or with SSMS, like [this](http://sqlserverplanet.com/dba/how-to-add-a-linked-server).

I've never created a linked server in MySQL, but in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370970/how-to-create-linked-server-mysql) you can find how to do it.

Hope it helps.