# Multiple Database Query MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two databases, database A and B which each have a table named general_table. How can I write a query that will do a cross search on both general_tables depending on Barcode Number (Each table contains Barcode Number) with connection:

```
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'pharmana_general', '123456', 'A');
```

Comment: what did you try already?

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Are both databases on the same server?

Comment: yes same server

Comment: Then just write the query as normal but prefix the table names with the database name.  `database.table.column`

Comment: SELECT *
FROM `pharmana_Hareket_db`.`general_Table` HDB, `pharmana_urun_db`.`general_Table` UDB
Where HDB.EczaneID = '101' AND HDB.Yil = '2017' AND HDB.Barkod = UDB.Barkod 
Group by UDB.Ana_Kategori
gives me unknow field Ana_Kategori error but i have that field

Comment: Please do not dump code in commments, it is unreadable. Edit your original question to add any new information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I construct a cross database query in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999235/how-do-i-construct-a-cross-database-query-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like, based on what you're trying, the best solution would be a union:

```
SELECT a.* FROM pharmana_Hareket_db.`general_Table` a 
UNION
SELECT b.* FROM pharmana_urun_db.`general_Table` b
```

Building on the above example, you could do:

```
SELECT a.* FROM pharmana_Hareket_db.`general_Table` a 
WHERE a.barCodeField = 1234567980
UNION
SELECT b.* FROM pharmana_urun_db.`general_Table` b
WHERE b.barCodeField = 1234567980
```

You could of course a use JOIN, depending on the data set up, but it sounds like a UNION would work for you.

Edit:  I have just read that you want both, so you could try a join

```
SELECT * FROM pharmana_Hareket_db.`general_Table` a 
INNER JOIN pharmana_urun_db.`general_Table` b
ON a.barCodeField = b.barCodeField
```

...which should only return rows that have matching barcodes in both DBs