# CakePHP: Joining two tables from two databases located on two different servers

Tags: mysql, sql, database, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Is it possible to do this in CakePHP? Can anyone give me an example how to join **`Comment`** table from **`db1`** located on `111.111.111.111` and **`User`** table from **`db2`** located on `222.222.222.222` where User is an owner of comment?

I'm putting my code below:

```
array(
  'Comment' => array('joins' => array(
     array(
       'table' => '[222.222.222.222].[db2].[User]',
       'alias' => 'UserJoin',
       'type' => 'INNER',
       'conditions' => array(
         "AND" => array('UserJoin.user_id = Comment.user_id')
       )
     )
   ), 
   'order' => array('Comment.id' => 'desc'),
   'fields' => array('UserJoin.*', 'Comment.*')
))
```

Comment: no. You can join tables only in one database.

Comment: @Jakuje that's not true http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972943/how-do-i-construct-a-cross-database-query-in-mysql But I'm not sure the Cake3 ORM supports it.

Comment: @burzum ok, but joining databases between two servers should not be possible.

Comment: Thanks @burzum but I'm working with Cake2 where ORM isn't available (I think).

Comment: @Jakuje http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html this works as well with the federated storage engine. verdun3r Cake2 has a ORM as well.